# Omitir campos vacios en consulta UnPivot

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy generando una consulta UnPivot para mostrarla en un DGV en C#, pero estoy obteniendo errores al toparme con campos vacíos cuando hago el recorrido con un foreach ya que extraigo el valor de la columna pero si esta vacio me finaliza el código, entonces mi pregunta es como puedo omitir desde el UnPivot aquellos campos vacíos o desde C# saltarse los campos vacios.

En Sql intente algo como esto pero me sigue mostrando los campos vacíos:

```
    ALTER Proc [dbo].[ShowUnpivotVal]

@idAppName int
AS
SELECT U.idCod, U.Cod, 
U.ColName, 
U.OutputVal, 
U.state, 
U.idAplicacion
FROM ExternalData 
unpivot
(
OutputVal
  FOR ColName in (Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4, Text5)
) U
WHERE idAplicacion = @idAppName and OutputVal IS NOT NULL--No me funciono con Is Not Null
```

En C# lo intente así pero tampoco me remueve los rows vacíos, asumo que es por la consulta:

```
idCod = Convert.ToInt32(DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                    nPart = DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    ColName  = DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();//Columna que va al 
                    Case
                    OutVal = DGVLCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();//Esta columna puede 
                    tener campos vacíos

                    //if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Cells[3].ToString()))//Intente con IsNullOrEmpty
                    //if (r.Cells["OutVal"].Value.ToString() == "")//Intente pasando el nombre de la 
                         columna
                    if (r.ToString()=="")//Intente removiendo el row si esta vacío pero no lo hace
                        {
                        DGVCodes.Rows.Remove(r);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    switch (DGVCodes.Rows[r.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString())
```

Los registros son n, y los campos vacios pueden varias en diferentes rows y columnas en el rango Text1 al Text5.

[image: Tabla Sql]

[image: Consulta UnPivot]

Espero me puedan ayudar, de antemano gracias.

DS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera parte es implementar el escenario tal cual lo has expuesto.

```
create table dbo.ExternalData
             (
             idCod        int
           , Cod          varchar(10)
           , text1        varchar(50)
           , text2        varchar(50)
           , text3        varchar(50)
           , text4        varchar(50)
           , text5        varchar(50)
           , State        varchar(20)
           , idAplicacion int
             );
```

Con la tabla creada, vamos a llenar con los valores. Aquí es donde hay que reseñar, lo que indicas como "vacio", puesto que de una imagen no se entiende.

Voy a exponer dos ejemplos.

```
insert into dbo.ExternalData
values
(1,'A9125244','TS 2-STAGE','Alerta de Calidad', 'Aplicar Lubricante','','Mandar Muestra','Esperando',7),
(2,'A9125247','TS 2-STAGE','Alerta de Calidad+Aviso', 'Aplicar Lubricante','Aplicar Sellado','','Enviado',9);
```

Vacio = ''

Por tanto la misma consulta de unpivot que has expuesto pero con la restricción de vacio.

```
SELECT U.idCod, U.Cod, 
           U.ColName, 
           U.OutputVal, 
           U.state, 
           U.idAplicacion
FROM ExternalData 
unpivot
(
OutputVal
  FOR ColName in (Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4, Text5)
) U
where u.OutputVal <> ''
```

[image: Result]

La segunda opción es vacio = null

```
delete from dbo.ExternalData
insert into dbo.ExternalData
values
(1,'A9125244','TS 2-STAGE','Alerta de Calidad', 'Aplicar Lubricante',null,'Mandar Muestra','Esperando',7),
(2,'A9125247','TS 2-STAGE','Alerta de Calidad+Aviso', 'Aplicar Lubricante','Aplicar Sellado',null,'Enviado',9);
```

Pero para esta opción no es necesario aplicar nada, ya que unpivot te quitará las filas que contengan null

```
SELECT U.idCod, U.Cod, 
           U.ColName, 
           U.OutputVal, 
           U.state, 
           U.idAplicacion
FROM ExternalData 
unpivot
(
OutputVal
  FOR ColName in (Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4, Text5)
) U
```

[image: Resultado]

Una última opción, es que contenga caracteres que no se visualizan en la imagen, tipo tabuladores, intros, espacios o similar. Pero si es el caso, deberías de determinar cuales y excluirlos de la misma manera.

Adicionalmente, la consulta tal cual la tienes, si quieres hacer cosas con sus columnas que por la casuística que fuera no te permite, la puedes envolver completamente en una tabla derivada y de ella aplicas los condicionantes que te interesen.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT U.idCod, U.Cod, 
           U.ColName, 
           U.OutputVal, 
           U.state, 
           U.idAplicacion
FROM ExternalData 
unpivot
(
OutputVal
  FOR ColName in (Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4, Text5)
) U
) AS miNuevaQuery
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma fácil y rápida para corregir tu error es en la consulta en lugar de traer NULL el valor del campo lo puedes reemplazar por una cadena de texto vacía, esto es:

```
ALTER Pr SELECT U.idCod, U.Cod, U.ColName, 
ISNULL(U.OutputVal,''), -- VERIFICAMOS SI EL CAMPO ES NULL Y SI ES SE SETEA COMO CADENA VACÍA
U.state, 
U.idAplicacion
FROM ExternalData 
unpivot
(
OutputVal
  FOR ColName in (Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4, Text5)
) U
WHERE idAplicacion = @idAppName
```

De esta forma no tendrás problemas manejando valores nullos en C#.

Otra forma de hacerlo desde código si no lo quieres hacer desde SQL es validando antes de asignar el valor si el campo del DGV es un valor null, esto lo puedes hacer tan fácil como con un if o hacerte un método de extensión en el cual puedar facilmente evitar esta clase de errores en el futuro, sin embargo con la primer solución de SQL debería de funcionar.